# where does Speed Dial firefox extension store user bookmarks'?

Tags: firefox, backup, firefox-extensions, url

I've lost my URLs in [Speed Dial](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/speed-dial/).

However I have found what appears to be a backup file (extension .speedial). How can I restore my URLs from this file?

Where does Speed Dial store its user bookmarks?

Answer (score 1):

- In Firefox click on Tools and then on Add-ons.
- When the Add-ons dialog opens up find Speed Dial and click on Options.
- In the Options dialog click on Settings and then in the drop-down click on Export Settings.
- A file dialog will come up and you can determine where to save the settings.
- You can copy this file to another computer or send it by email to yourself.
- In the new copy of Firefox with Speed Dial just repeat the process.
- Click Tools, then Add-ons, the click on Speed Dial, then click on Options.
- Then click on Settings, select Import Settings and select the file you exported.
- Your new copy of Speed Dial will match the original exactly!

Comment: I edited your answer, please use the WYSIWYG box to check how the text in the editor looks like next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore backup files by going to the following:

Speed Dial options > Parameters > Restore/Backup

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DialGrid](http://dialgrid.appspot.com) where speed dials are stored online and are accessible with any browser. There is no need to back them up.
All speed dial bookmarks are stored on the server.

Comment: please disclose your affiliation